# 14.04 GNOME, multi-task windows not hiding when searching from start menu

Tags: gnome, 14.04

Normally in GNOME when you hit the super key it explodes all the windows (to multi-task between them), then if you start to search the windows disappear and your search results are displayed.

However, since upgrading to 14.04 the windows still appear over the search results.

Here's an image of what I mean:

[image]

See how I'm searching for files in the background, yet my Chrome window isn't disappearing?

Is this a known issue or something specific to my installation?

I'm using the open source AMD graphics drivers if that's relevant.

Comment: For the record I resolved this issue by switching to proprietary drivers.